# How to create an int file

Tags: c, file, int, writefile, shared-file

I am trying to create a shared file, which has to be int.

```
int f;
```

However, when I reach

```
if ((fstat(f, &stbuf) != 0) || (!S_ISREG(stbuf.st_mode)))
```

It gives me an error. The file must contain a string like:

```
abcd
```

My guess is the following, but it does not work:

```
int main() {
  int f;
  void *memoria = NULL;
  int tam;
  struct stat stbuf;
  char string[15] = {0};

  f = open("fichero.txt", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR);

  // ERROR IS HERE!!
  if ((fstat(f, &stbuf) != 0) || (!S_ISREG(stbuf.st_mode))) {
    printf("Error");
  }

  tam = stbuf.st_size;
  printf("%d\n", tam);

  // Proyect the file
  memoria = mmap(0, tam, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, f, 0);
  // Copy the string into the file
  memcpy(memoria, "abcd", 5);

  munmap(memoria, tam);

  return 0;
}
```

Should I change the parameters in open??
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us the error message you get ?

Comment: You don't check if the `open` succeeded and you don't output the specific error. That makes debugging impossible.

Comment: Segmentation fault. I think I am trying to access a file that I haven't created, but I do not want to do that, I want to actually generate it.

Comment: The thing is that I am not trying to open it, I want to create it. I just do not know how to.

Comment: Accept my edit don't copy and paste... I take time to indent your code! http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14534511

Comment: Check if `open` returns -1 which indicates that the file could not be opened and if yes, then don't proceed any further but display an error message. If you want to create a file, then maybe you need [`creat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html). BTW there is no such thing as an _int file_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `O_CREAT` mode to create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
f = open("fichero.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
```

You should check for errors from `open()`:

```
if (f == -1) {
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: It tells me there is an error creating the file: Permission denied.

Comment: You're trying to create the file in a directory you don't have write permission to.

Comment: Try using the full pathname so it creates the file in a directory you can write.

Comment: It is the downloads directory, is that normal? Can I solve it with sudo?

Comment: Hey, so I am trying to copy my string like this  memcpy(memoria,string,sizeof(string)); and it gives me a bus error. Do you have any idea why? (Last question I swear lol)

Comment: You can't grow a file with `mmap()`. If you just created the file, it will be empty, so there's no memory to map. You should use `ftruncate()` to set the length of the file before you map it.

Comment: Thank you so much!